# What variable to use when I'm not sure what the input will be?

Tags: c++, input

I have to use "overloading functions" for this assignment. 
I understand the concept and how they work, but I don't understand how can I get input from the user then if I don't know what it will be?

I am supposed to get input from a user and it can either be a string, double or a array of int's. I have to figure out what the input will be and use the correct function for it.

My issue is when I get the user to input the data, where do I store it when I don't know what it will be? I mean once I stored it I can compare and found out what the data type is which I have an idea how to do.

Any one know?

Comment: You could store it as a string and parse it accordingly

Comment: I think we need some more context.  What are you going to do with the value that the user enters?  Do you need to treat everything uniformly?  Can you just hardcode in a few cases?

Comment: The data entered will be grades. Either "A" "A+" etc (strings), 12.43% etc (double) or five marks, ie 34 59 98 92 (max of five, (the array)). 
It must then be put into it's according function. Then just spit out a simple text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you get input from the user, it will be a string. Period. You then have to parse it to see what it is. While you are writing a parser, you might find a use for overloaded functions.

Comment: parse it? can you explain more please.

Comment: No, I can't. It's your homework, not mine, for one thing, and I fear that I'll send you in the wrong direction for your teachers' satisfaction. Did they give you sample inputs? Further, the instructions seem backwards. Since the input in this case is always a string, it's going to take some artificial gyrations to find a reason to overload anything.

Comment: No this is to get us used to using and understand the concept behind how overloaded functions work. So we must use them. One function that can take in three inputs (well three function I guess). And fair enough. Google parse it is haha. I'm not sure what that means. Thanks though.

Comment: Parsing is how you take a string containing, say, "123456" and end up with an 'int' containing 123456. You must have a more complex job involving a variety of strings with a variety of contents.

Comment: Wait. That's called parsing? So doing something like (int)("12345") kinda deal?

Comment: @Robsta: No, that's casting, and it will not give you any meaningful results in this case.  Functions that do parsing are, for example, `atoi`, `strtol`, `stoi`, `stod` and `boost::lexical_cast`

Comment: Oh boy. Never heard of any of those ....
Man. This is turning out to be much more difficult than I thought..

Comment: Let's throw another term into the group: tokenize.. You'll probably need to google that to parse "arrays" :P.

Comment: Well. I figured out another method to figure out all my inputs and such. But, without you guys hinting me and helping me I wouldn't have figured it out. Thank you. (:

Answer (score 0):

Well, a string can hold numbers within itself, so go with that.  You can test if for digits and decimal points to see if it's a number.

Answer (score 0):

you receive an input from the command line console, one option to do this cleanly is to have users force to tell what they are entering. i.e. display a note something like for grades enter "grade" A+ or whatever, "percentage" 123, "marks" five sub marks. In this way you can check the first argument to call overloaded function and use the next arguments as values. Do some checking to make sure that after "grade" they dont enter percentage or marks. Not sure if this your assignment is flexible to do this but its more easier for users.

For convertion from string to any other type you could use a template function like below

```
    template <class outputType>
    outputType ClassName::strOutputType(std::string val)  // converts string to other using string stream
    {
       outputType ot;
       std::istringstream out(val);
       out>> ot;
       return ot;
    }
```

Comment: Can't do that. It literally has to be just a question lets say, "please enter the students marks:" and the program has to figure out what kinda of data, and what function to use for it.

Comment: so you have to take those arguments and then have some conditions to determine the type of data -1. check the number of arguments if not > 1 they can't be marks. 2. then check if you can convert first arg to double if yes its percentage if not then they are grades. Otherwise get for 5sub marks and process them.

Comment: That's super confusing. Sorry. I didn't quite understand what you were trying to say?